# Как настроить оси в PyQtGraph?

Tags: python, ооп, gui, pyqt, pyqtgraph

Возникла следующая проблема:

- если первый элемент массива **`y = 950`**, размерность ординаты верно отображается. (Изображение 1)
- если первый элемент массива **`y = 1000`**, размерность ординаты отображаются, как **`y / 1000`**. (Изображение 2)

Как исправить это и отображать верные значения?

Вот пример кода:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 190, 721, 281))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 120, 191, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.p1 = self.set_graph_ui()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.graphic)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "график"))

    def set_graph_ui(self):
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
        win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(win)
        p1 = win.addPlot(title="График")
        p1.setMouseEnabled(False, False)
        p1.setLabel('left', text='Высота', color='white', units='м')
        p1.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        p1.setLogMode(x=False, y=False)
        p1.setLabel('bottom', text='Расстояние', color='white', units='км')
        win.setBackground("w")
        return p1

    def graphic(self):
        self.p1.clear()
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        y = [950, 950, 900, 850, 800, 750, 700, 650, 600, 550]
        self.p1.plot(x, y, pen={'color': 'k', 'width': 2}, name='График')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Изображение 1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Изображение 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Vadim, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Исправил вопрос и добавил пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self._low, self._high, self._size = -200, 1500, 10
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Обновить график')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.plot) 

        self.plotWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.plotWidget.setBackground('k')  
        self.plotWidget.setLabel('left', text='Высота (м)', color='white')
        self.plotWidget.setLabel('bottom', text='Расстояние', color='white', units='км')
# !!!
        self.plotWidget.setXRange(0, 10, padding= 0.02)                     # !!!   10
        self.plotWidget.setYRange(0, 1200)                                  # !!! 1200
# !!!
        self.plotWidget.setTitle("График", color='w')
        self.plotWidget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.plotWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        self.plotWidget.clear()
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        y = list(np.random.randint(self._low, self._high, self._size)) 
# попробуйте так:
        self.plotWidget.plot(x, y, pen="y", name="Yellow")
# или так:
#        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0), width=3, style=QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
#        self.plotWidget.plot(x, y, symbol='o', pen=pen)
       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]